# Set values from source table before SQL merge

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, sql-server-2012

Here's what I'm dreaming of doing and I emphasize dreaming. This is quite possibly impossible.

What I want to do (in the best way I can describe it) is to set variables in a merge statement using data from the source table. These variables, such as the example below, will manipulate the source data before merging with the Target table. Can this be done and if so, how?

Thanks in advance.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_MergeCompetedCasesIntoManifest

AS BEGIN

declare @TicketType char(1)

SET @TicketType = SourceTable.CaseVoided --SourceTable not bound yet, clearly impossible.

SELECT CASE when @TicketType = 0
THEN
    'T'
ELSE
    'V'
END

MERGE TargetTable AS TargetTable
USING SourceTable AS SourceTable
ON TargetTable.CASE_SERIAL_NUMBER = SourceTable.SerialNumber

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT 

(   CASE_SERIAL_NUMBER,
    TICKET_TYPE
)

VALUES

(   SourceTable.SerialNumber
    @TicketType              --Something like this would be nice...
)

    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET

TargetTable.TICKET_TYPE = @TicketType;       --Same here...

END
```

**EDIT**
I think @user1178676 is on the right track, unfortunately after seeing his solution, I ran into other parts of this SP that needed help. Here's another variable I need to set. It's basically taking a column out of the source table and converting it into string fields to match the target table's needs.

```
declare @DateTime datetime
declare @DateProcessed char(18)

SET @DateTime = CONVERT(datetime, (select SourceTable.PrintDateTime)
SET @DateProcessed = CONVERT(char(18), CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(YYYY, @DateTime)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(MM, @DateTime))
                             + '/' +     CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(dd, @DateTime)) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(HH, @DateTime))
                             + ':' +     CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(MI, @DateTime)) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(SS, @DateTime)))
```

What I need this to spit out is a field called 'ProductionDate' (an ugly string converted from the datetime 'PrintDateTime' from the source table. This would need to be set similarly to ticket type but obviously this isn't a CASE scenario. Is there similar syntax to include something like this in the select as well?
Thanks again.

Comment: Are you just trying to avoid repeating the CASE expression in two places in the MERGE statement? Do you want it evaluated for each row being processed?

Comment: @HABO, I'm wanting to evaluate for each row, yes. Basically, this is a fancy merge of one table into another table that contains similar data but is represented very differently. The point of the SP is to avoid a C# app to do the conversion work.

Comment: Well, you might want to replace that little date formatting expression with this: `Convert( Char(10), SourceTable.PrintDateTime, 111 ) + ' ' + Convert( Char(8), SourceTable.PrintDateTime, 108 )`

Comment: Thanks @HABO, very helpful comment. I had it way too complicated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server allows the use of variables in merge statements, but if I understand your needs correctly, you can do this without using variables.  I'd recommend converting your source table into a query where the row logic lives there.

Here's how I'd change things:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_MergeCompetedCasesIntoManifest

AS BEGIN


MERGE TargetTable AS TargetTable
USING (
       select SerialNumber,
       case when CaseVoided = 1 then 'T' else 'V' end as TicketType,
       CONVERT(char(18), CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(YYYY, @DateTime)) + '/' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(MM, @DateTime))
                         + '/' +     CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(dd, @DateTime)) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(HH, @DateTime))
                         + ':' +     CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(MI, @DateTime)) + ':' + CONVERT(varchar,DATEPART(SS, @DateTime))) as ProductionDate
       from SourceTable

       ) AS SourceTable
ON TargetTable.CASE_SERIAL_NUMBER = SourceTable.SerialNumber

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT 

(   CASE_SERIAL_NUMBER,
    TICKET_TYPE,
    ProductionDate
)

VALUES

(   SourceTable.SerialNumber,
    SourceTable.TicketType,              --removed the variable, added the ColumnName of the new source table
    ProductionDate
)

    WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET

TargetTable.TICKET_TYPE = SourceTable.TicketType --removed the variable, added the ColumnName of the new source table
targetTable.ProductionDate = SourceTable.ProductionDate;       

END
```

I think this should get you what you need.  Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding things.

Comment: I think this would work for my initial example. I edited my post to include another instance that I hope could be included in the select as well somehow. What do you think?

Comment: Again, I don't believe you need to use variables here.  I've modified the merge statement to include your date column.

Comment: Thanks @user1178676. This got me on the right track and my new merge works great! Merge is awesome.